# Viewing a pdf file in a new tab or window from a file in memory...MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC3 app that allows the user to dowload a file to their hard drive or view it in a browser. The file is stored on a filesher thats not accessible to the internet. So the file's byte array is stored in memory and then sent to the browser like this:

```
            /// <summary>
    /// overrides actionresult method so document can be viewed in browser window
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        // get current context and set values
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.Clear();
        response.BufferOutput = false;   // to prevent buffering 
        response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        response.ContentType = ContentType;
        response.AddHeader("Content-Length", Length.ToString());

        var ext = Path.GetExtension(FileName);

        if (!Show)
        response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + FileName+ "\"");

        response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

        var stream = new MemoryStream(ContentBytes);
        stream.WriteTo(response.OutputStream);
        stream.Dispose();

    }
```

I cant view pdfs for some reason. I can download them but not view them. Im attaching a sample project here [showinbrowser.zip](http://troy-compton.com/files/showinbrowser.zip). Its VS2010 sp1. Can someone show me how to display a PDF file in a new browser window/tab thats stored in memory? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the `Controller.File` method which handles this for you ?

```
public ActionResult _ShowDocument(string id)
{
  byte[] fileData=GetByteArrayFilefromId(id);
  return File(fileData,"application/pdf","somefile.pdf");
}
```

Comment: Tried that, i think the problem may be with a javascript. Have u ran the sample code i attached?

Comment: Javascript has nothing to do with this. When you run the above code it will show the PDF in the browser. What problem you are facing ?

Comment: I have tried it but it is giving an option to open/save. But I am looking to open pgd if new IE tab.

Answer (score 1):

hi set your content type to pdf

```
//Set the appropriate ContentType.
     Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
```

Comment: Hi..Im setting all this stuff. I included a sample project. I didnt want to post a bunch of code